# Java generic class as parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a basic question regarding Java generics. I have a method that takes this as an argument:

```
public id findKey(List<String> ids, CustomClass clazz) {
    repos.findID(ids, clazz);
}
```

I then want to use a java generic class as an argument for another method:

```
repos.findID(ids, clazz);
```

but my findID method needs a java generic class instead of clazz. How do I get my clazz argument from the findkey parameter and turn it to a generic class? If I do this:

```
public id findKey(List<String> ids, Class<T> clazz) {
    repos.findID(ids, clazz);
}
```

I get an error because it won't recognize my T.

I'm at loss at how this stuff works and would appreciate any help.

Edit: Solved it. I can use ? or explicitly state a class type that I wanted and it accepted it.

Comment: Unless you actually need `T` elsewhere in your method, `Class<?>` is sufficient. Otherwise, just define a type variable: `public <T> id findKey(...`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it like 10 seconds after posting this.

Comment: then please answer it yourself - maybe it helps someone else

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger indeed: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- define your type as unknown

  ```
  public id findKey(List<String> ids, Class<?> clazz)
  ```
- define a type variable

  ```
  public <T> id findKey(List<String> ids, Class<T> clazz)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `public id findKey(List<String> ids, Class<?> clazz)` and read more about wildcards